# Retrieve Images from database on the basis of json data

Tags: android, json, database, firebase-realtime-database

Currently I am developing an application which displays cricket scores from an api. The api returns json data of a list of live matches, which has a unique id of every match. By passing unique id of match in url, we get entire scorecard of match. But, this doesn't return photos of the players playing. So i want to display them in an imageview along with playername, Runs, Balls, boundaries,etc.[image: Scorecard]

Something like this.. What's the best way? Firebase Or something else?

Comment: from where you are getting photos of the players ?

Comment: I think i'll manually download it from espncricinfo.. Is there any other way?

Comment: Try using universal image loader https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Comment: Have you tried using [tag:picasso]? Then maybe in your Firebase DB is where the link of the photos. For the photo storage, maybe [tag:firebase-storage]?

Comment: No, I haven't tried yet. But I'm trying to do it. Yes, firebase storage is a great option.But, I don't think there's a URL generated, is a system path like gs://fb-storage//xyz.png

Answer (score 1):

You need to use libraries like [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) for loading images from any link.

And for links of images you can maintain static array of URL's of images **or** you may write some dynamic code by which links of profile images will be extracted from the json id's (by requesting on some generic URL using those id's) you already have so that you need not to maintain any static array.

Comment: But how do i maintain some mapping like if playerName="Virat Kohli" it should fetch his photo?

Comment: @KARANCHAPANERI you can maintain hash map for that. If name is "xyz" the link will be "abc.com" something like that

Comment: Ok..Thanks for information. I'll let you know when i bump into some blunders.. Can we chat one-to-one otherwise?

Comment: @KARANCHAPANERI yes why not. also accept my answer if that's helpful to you. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah.. I am thinking to go with your answer.. But, concern is size of hash map, around about 140 manual entries of the links.. Ummm.

Comment: @KARANCHAPANERI having 140 entries in hashmap will not matter as it consume very less size. But As in my answer, I suggest you to generate those links using some dynamic code(I can't tell you exactly because I didn't ever gone through espncricinfo api's). Because if you maintain static links then every time new player comes in espncricinfo you need to update your complete app to playstore which is not feasible solution.

Comment: What about Firebase? I find it fascinating

Comment: @KARANCHAPANERI Yes. you can go with it